# Detect if page was redirected or loaded directly(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, session-cookies

Currently, I want to display a label on the first page of my site a user visits.

To make it simple, say I only care about page1.html and page2.html.

Is it possible to check if the user was redirected from page1.html to page2.html?(Perhaps with cookies?)

Edit:
On page1.html, I set a cookie, which would expire in a minute. On page2.html, I checked for the cookie. Works great!

Comment: On the page1.html you set some cookie variable to `true` and on other pages you set this variable to false. If you want to check if previous page was page1.html you just check this variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `document.referrer`.

The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link).

1. For example when user come to URL via bookmaked links click.
2. User type the full URL in address bar.

> Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: `document.referrer` only works when user is on a page and clicks on a link to open an other page.

Comment: The title says **Detect if page was redirected or loaded directly(Javascript)**.  But `document.referrer` is not accessible in redirection.