# Javascript Determine if page was opened by <a href> tag or window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, redirect

The question is pretty much the same as the title.

Is there a way in Javascript to determine whether the page was opened by `<a href>` HTML tag or by `window.location.href`?

I need conditions for clearing saved states of data-table:

> on reload

and

> on opened via `<a href>` tag.

I don't want to clear saved states when opened via **window.location.href**.

I got one `on reload`:

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1){
      var table = $('#categoryList').DataTable();
      table.state.clear();
      table.search("").draw(); 
      table.column( '0:visible' ).order( 'asc' ).draw();
      table.page.len(10).draw();
    }
```

I'm looking for another one `on oponed via <a href>`.

Comment: I think this is the solution you're looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522178/detect-if-page-was-redirected-or-loaded-directlyjavascript

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already checked with this condition                       
                                                                                                                                        if (document.referrer && !document.referrer.includes('animalCategor') || performance.navigation.type === 1) {}
                                                                                                                                                              but what if there are multiple routes that contains "animalCategor" ?

Comment: _"but what if there are multiple routes that contains animalCategor?"_ - well be more specific in what you want to match then?

Comment: Yes, thanks, and if we don't want to clear saved states on a back button from anywhere if (document.referrer && !document.referrer.includes('fanPagePost') && performance.navigation.type != 2 || performance.navigation.type === 1){} it will work!.